# monitoring twilio call with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, twilio

I'm trying to monitoring the status of a call that is happening between two persons using phone numbers. Imagine that +558512344321 and +558543211234 are in a call. Soon as that call starts, I have to show in the browser: "Call in progress" and soon it's been completed, the browser gonna show me "call completed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need real time status updates of the call, one possible option is to push both calls into a conference.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference

Set a status callback url when you dial the conference:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent

And listen for the conference end event.

Comment: The problem is that I'll be forced to make a request every time to the server to see the status of the call. I mean, there's no way to start the request by the server and give that result to the browser by javascript? Maybe websocket?

Comment: When Twilio makes a post to your server page on conference end, you broadcast that to the websocket to which the clients are listening.

Comment: There's a tutorial on doing this using [Node.js, socket.io and React](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/11/reactjs-tutorial-call-monitoring-with-react-express-and-socket-io.html) that might be of interest. You might be able to apply that to your situation.